# Apache Camel and annotation based coping all values from fields in one java bean to another

Tags: java, annotations, apache-camel, javabeans

I have 2 java beans

Source Java Bean

```
 import java.util.Date;
 public class MySource { 
     int a;
     String b;
     double c;
     Date myd;
     AnotherClass obj;
 }

public class AnotherClass {
    String str;
    String str_2;
    List<Long> data;
}
```

Destination Java Bean

```
import java.util.Date;
 public class MyDest { 
    // From MySource.a field
    int a_d;

    // From MySource.b field
    String b_d;

    // From MySource.c field
    double c_d;

    // From MySource.myd field
    Date myd;

    // From MySource.AnotherClass.str field
    String str_df;

    // From MySource.AnotherClass.str_2 field
    String str_dfr;

    // From MySource.AnotherClass.data field
    List<Long> data;
}
```

How do I Transform/coping all values from fields Source java bean to Destination java bean using apache Camel and annotation

Comment: How much do you understand about Camel? Have you tried creating a route yet?

Comment: Take a look at camel-dozer: http://camel.apache.org/dozer - it can do data mapping between POJOs.

Comment: @Claus I am trying camel-dozer component but was successful. Trying the POC on it. If u some good working example, which u can share it will be great.